# Why the interrupt service routine ,PUSH {r3,r4,r5,lr} but POP {r0,r4,r5,lr},which lead to ERROR?

Tags: c, arm, iar

I am using IAR to compile routines, but run error on ARM A7; then i got the question below when i open the *.lst* file generated by IAR.
    It is a `ISR`, first `push {r3, r4, r5, lr}`, but `POP {r0, r4, r5, lr}` when return, the `R0` value is changed to the value of `R3` before push. So `R0` is wrong when returned from `irqHandler` which lead to error in follow routines. 
    why ?

```
    void irqHandler(void)
    {
         878:   e92d4038    push    {r3, r4, r5, lr}
      volatile u32 *pt = (u32 *)AM_INTC_BASE;
         87c:   e3a044b0    mov r4, #176, 8 ; 0xb0000000
      u32 id_spin;

      id_spin = *(pt+0x200c/4) & 0x3ff;
         880:   e302000c    movw    r0, #8204   ; 0x200c
         884:   e7900004    ldr r0, [r0, r4]
         888:   e1b00b00    lsls    r0, r0, #22
         88c:   e1b00b20    lsrs    r0, r0, #22
         890:   e1b05000    movs    r5, r0
      if(id_spin<32)
         894:   e3550020    cmp r5, #32
         898:   2a000000    bcs 8a0 <irqHandler+0x28>
      {
    #ifdef WHOLECHIPSIM
        print("id_spid<32 error...\r\n",0);
    #endif    
        while(1);
         89c:   eafffffe    b   89c <irqHandler+0x24>
      }
      else
      {
        (pFuncIrq[id_spin-32])();
         8a0:   e59f0010    ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; 8b8 <.text_8>
         8a4:   e1b01105    lsls    r1, r5, #2
         8a8:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
         8ac:   e5100080    ldr r0, [r0, #-128] ; 0x80
         8b0:   e12fff30    blx r0
      }
    }
         8b4:   e8bd8031    pop {r0, r4, r5, pc}
```

Comment: I don't know IAR tools, but don't you need to add some keywords to tell the compiler that you want to use it as an ISR? Or is this just ommited in the snippet?

Comment: Tools know it is ISR; question is that before enter ISR ,the ISR doest not PUSH R0 into stack, which stored the parameter used by normal routine, So after returned from the ISR ,the routine failed because of wrong parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The abi requires a 64 bit aligned stack, so the push of r3 simply facilitates that.  Could have chosen any register not already specified.  Likewise on the pop they need to clean up the stack the function is prototyped as void so the return (r0) is a dont care and r0-r3 are not expected to be preserved so no reason to match the r3 on each end nor match an r0 on each end.

had they chose a register numbered above r3 (r6 for example) on the push then that would have needed to be matched on the pop.  Otherwise the pop would have to be one of r0-r3 to not trash a non-volatile register. (couldnt push r3 then pop r6 that would trash r6)

Comment: note for an isr somewhere all the other registers need to be preserved, you say this is a cortex a7 so it is not doing that for you if it was a cortex-m it would be...But the r3 to r0 is pretty obvious here without talking about interrupts...

Comment: Yes,the cortex A7 won't store the context for you, after add code to save the Rx,problem solved.  but another question : if the A7 won't do that, why push{R3,R4,R5,R6,lr},and pop them, you know PUSH&POP will access the memory  which will affect the efficiency.

Comment: there is a blx so you are making a call, so lr has to be saved.  r4 and r5 are used by the code, the abi requires that you preserve these, this is just a function like any other function so the compiler compiles it and needs to preserve those.  That is an odd number of registers, the stack wouldnt be aligned on a 64 bit boundary, so it needs one more and the one more doesnt matter so much so long as you dont mess up a non-volatile register or the return value, there is no return value so that is what they did, chose one for the push and another for the pop.

Comment: perhaps the weird combination of dont care registers or perhaps across a whole binary they can use that as marker to know this was their compiler vs how gcc or other behaves, who knows...

Comment: depending on what mode you are in which the compiler doesnt know necessariy the return is an eret or sub pc,lr,#4 or something like that, which this function does neither, so the actual handler, the one that preserves the registers is the one that knows this is an interrupt, the compiler didnt know in this case and compiled it like any other function it appears.  Otherwise the compiler would have simply pushed everything on the stack and used the proper interrupt return (Although the programmer would have to tell the compiler which return to use based on mode (hyp vs irq/fiq))

Comment: when use IAR to write a ISR for cortex-A7,should use the keyword:__irq __arm, then the compiler will correctly process the context, PUSH,POP all is right , assemble code with the keyword is below:                                          878: e24ee004  sub lr, lr, #4
87c: e92d503f  push {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, ip, lr}                             .........                                                                                                         8b8: e8fd903f          ldm sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, ip, pc}                            restore not use the POP but ldm instead.

Comment: have post the whole assemble code with the keyword __irq __arm up;

Comment: Another question about alignment, you said 'That is an odd number of registers, the stack wouldnt be aligned on a 64 bit boundary'; I have check about the alignment from ARM manual , it tell me the alignment is only for the entry of function ,but not the STACK point, so what do you think ?

Comment: they have simply dictated a 64 bit (two word) alignment on the stack, I have seen the compilers do this in separate pushes and pops so there is an opportunity for an interrupt to come in and have an unaligned stack.  In this case there is a call, that function expects an aligned stack, so this function needs to push an even number of things so that when that call happens it gets an aligned stack.

Comment: not sure what your end goal is here, if you think it is performance then you want the extra word there for performance, remove it and it takes longer you might need a read-modify-write somewhere that you wouldnt need if doing 64 bit transfers.  may or may not require that depending your system and may or may not be able to detect it but that is very likely why it was added to the abi, performance.

Comment: there is no pop instruction in arm, it is a pseudo instruction for ldm, like push is an stmn generally stmdb/ldmia.

Comment: they are pushing and popping the volatile registers then the C function can be compiled normally (using the abi and nothing special) so this all makes sense.

Comment: I have check the CPU's running log,in A7, it just require word alignment in stack; So, i think word-aligned or 64bit-aligned depends on the width of bus,if the bus is 32bit, only 32bit-aligned stack is required, because it is enough to avoid the read-modify-write; if the bus is 64-bit, 64-bit aligned is needed, but in 32-bit bus system ,64-bit aligned stack also is OK, am i right? I have post the log pic(a link,i cant post picture here...) below ,as one answer.  In the log, you can see it just push 7 register it is odd.

Comment: the PUSH info in the log is another function call ,not the ISR.

Comment: the 64 bit aligned stack is a software requirement not a hardware requirement, but seems obvious as to why.  I cant imagine a cortex-a with a 32 bit axi bus but perhaps that is possible.  Still confused as to what your problem is here, the compiler did what it is told and it is for a sane reason and it doesnt hurt your program. It is a functionally correct implementation of your code.  There are no compiler bugs here, all is well...

Comment: my problem is my ISR doesn't work fine, when routine enter ISR , routine will failed... ,the reason is the IAR compiler doesn't know the ISR is a real ISR without keyword __irq __arm, so the generated assemble code  doesn't store&restore the context correctly, then ERROR happened; with the keyword  the generated assemble code store&restore the context correctly. the tool is well, it is fault of myself.

Comment: so now you are asking another question, please resolve this question in whatever way (close it or mark one of the answers correct) since this question is about the strange looking but understandable push and pop use for alignment.  then ask a new question related to why doesnt my interrupt work.   Before doing that simply try writing your own handler in asm or wrap a normal C function with the up front handler that saves state and restores state (of the registers that are not already preserved by the abi).

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter as R0-R3, R12, LR, PC, xPSR are saved on the stack automaticly  when the hardware invokes the interrupt vector routine. When `bx`, `ldm`, `pop`, or `ldr` with `PC` is invoked hardware executes interrupt routine exit poping those registers.

Do not check your compiler. It knows what it does. Check tour wrong logic - especially printing strings in the interrupt handler.

Comment: I know what you mean, the compiler know which register need to be push into stack,and when return from the ISR , also there are code for restore the register,then everything is fine;   but my question is that before enter ISR ,the ISR doest not PUSH R0 into stack, which stored the parameter used by normal routine, So after returned from the ISR ,the routine failed because of wrong parameter.

Comment: It restores R4 and R5, the rest is restored by the hardware

Comment: If you call the external functions in the ISR  make sure that those functions do not change other registers, unknown for the compiler. Your interrupt handling logic is wrong

Comment: the compiler PUSH {r3,r4,r5,lr} into stack instead of {r0,r4,r5,lr},  I think the reason PUSH R3 into stack is for aligning 8 bytes, so when the compiler analyze the code, compiler think R0 doesn't need to be stored. but in fact ,R0 stored the parameter used the the normal routine,so how compiler the determine which register should be stored ,and which one needn't ?

Comment: Now,i have commented the external functions you said , print function, but the result also is wrong and the same reason.

Comment: what result? Do not look into the generated code. If your function was called as an interrupt  you do not have to worry about R0-R3 at all. How Put the breakpoint inside th ISR then step over on the instruction level and you will see that your registers after pop will be restored.

Comment: I am SOC engineer; I have the CPU-IP , and i can see the CPU's working timing wave, so i can see everything ,include all the register. i see than R0 have been restored with R3's pre-value, which is used as a address pointer.

Comment: i afraid you do not understand R0, R1, R2, R3, R12, PC, LR, xPSP are stored by the **hardware** and restored by the hardware! You will not see it in your assembly listing. You call functions which have unknown register behaviour (R4,R5 ...) in the ISR via pointers and directly. C function do not have to restore all registers. Maybe your "handler" is called as a callback not invoked as intertupt. The generated code is absolutely fine.

Comment: From software view,R0, R1, R2, R3, R12, PC, LR, xPSP are stored by the hardware, that's right; in fact ,the PUSH,POP also have the corresponding assemble code, if no code tell HARDWARE, HARDWARE how to known where should do PUSH/POP? i can see the hardware push&pop behavior, restore R0 from which address;

Comment: there is another issue in this code. I am not sure but `blx` also does the the interrupt exit. There should be bl instead. Then when it returns pop PC will not provide the interrupt exit - just the "normal one" and your registers will not be restored. Remove this call and see then.

Comment: If the hardware doesn't know that the hardware ist doing an inerrupt, who else should know? If the hardware stores R0-3 on interrupt entry, you don't need to do it again in software.

Comment: Hi, thank you,everyone! question have been solved;  for ARM-A7 core, the work storing the context should be done by software in a ISR, so if there is no code for save Rx, the data will be lost.

Comment: but another question : if the A7 won't do that, why push{R3,R4,R5,R6,lr},and pop them, you know PUSH&POP will access the memory  which will affect the efficiency.

Comment: Ask iar instead. They are authors of the compiler

Answer (score 0):

assemble code with the keyword __irq __arm is below:

```
    __irq __arm void irqHandler(void)
    {
         878:   e24ee004    sub lr, lr, #4
         87c:   e92d503f    push    {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, ip, lr}
      volatile u32 *pt = (u32 *)AM_INTC_BASE;
         880:   e3a044b0    mov r4, #176, 8 ; 0xb0000000
      u32 id_spin;

      id_spin = *(pt+0x200c/4) & 0x3ff;
         884:   e302000c    movw    r0, #8204   ; 0x200c
         888:   e7900004    ldr r0, [r0, r4]
         88c:   e1b00b00    lsls    r0, r0, #22
         890:   e1b00b20    lsrs    r0, r0, #22
         894:   e1b05000    movs    r5, r0
      if(id_spin<32)
         898:   e3550020    cmp r5, #32
         89c:   2a000000    bcs 8a4 <irqHandler+0x2c>
      {
    #ifdef WHOLECHIPSIM
        print("id_spid<32 error...\r\n",0);
    #endif    
        while(1);
         8a0:   eafffffe    b   8a0 <irqHandler+0x28>
      }
      else
      {
        (pFuncIrq[id_spin-32])();
         8a4:   e59f0010    ldr r0, [pc, #16]   ; 8bc <.text_8>
         8a8:   e1b01105    lsls    r1, r5, #2
         8ac:   e0910000    adds    r0, r1, r0
         8b0:   e5100080    ldr r0, [r0, #-128] ; 0x80
         8b4:   e12fff30    blx r0
      }
    }
         8b8:   e8fd903f    ldm sp!, {r0, r1, r2, r3, r4, r5, ip, pc}^
```

Answer (score 0):

Cortex A7 PUSH log ,it just push 7 register, so 32bit aligned is ok

follow link is the log info:

http://img.blog.csdn.net/20170819120758443?watermark/2/text/aHR0cDovL2Jsb2cuY3Nkbi5uZXQvcmFpbmJvd2JpcmRzX2Flcw==/font/5a6L5L2T/fontsize/400/fill/I0JBQkFCMA==/dissolve/70/gravity/Center